# Проблема отображение изображения в pygame

Tags: python, изображения, pygame

Код лабиринта с жёлтым квадратом

```
import os
import random
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')

class Player(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)
        
        
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        
        # Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)
    
    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        
        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

# Nice class to hold a wall rect
class Wall(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

# Initialise pygame
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

# Set up the display
pygame.display.set_caption("Ainel")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = [] # List to hold the walls
player = Player() # Create the player

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W                      W",
"W         WWWWWW       W",
"W   WWWW       W   WWW W",
"W   W        WWWW      W",
"W WWW  WWWW      WWWWWWW",
"W   W     W W          W",
"W   W     W   WWW     WW",
"W   WWW WWW   W W      W",
"W     W   W   W W WWWW W",
"WWW   W   WWWWW W   WWWW",
"W W      WW            W",
"W W   WWWW   WWW WWW   W",
"W     W    E   W       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

running = True
while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
    
    # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(-2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -2)
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.move(0, 2)
    
    # Just added this to make it slightly fun ;)
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        raise SystemExit
    
    # Draw the scene
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: Изображение игрока]

Код игрока с изображением

```
import pygame
import random

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        
    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
        # Keep player on the screen
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

# Initialize pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

player = Player()

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    # Get all the keys currently pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # Update the player sprite based on user keypresses
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    # Fill the screen with black
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Draw the player on the screen
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Я пытался заменить жёлтый квадрат изображением, но ничего не получалось.
Жёлтый квадрат не изменялся.

Вот изменённый код

```
import os
import random
import pygame

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)
        
        
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        
        # Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)
    
    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        
        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

# Nice class to hold a wall rect
class Wall(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

# Initialise pygame
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

# Set up the display
pygame.display.set_caption("Ainel")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = [] # List to hold the walls
player = Player() # Create the player

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W                      W",
"W         WWWWWW       W",
"W   WWWW       W   WWW W",
"W   W        WWWW      W",
"W WWW  WWWW      WWWWWWW",
"W   W     W W          W",
"W   W     W   WWW     WW",
"W   WWW WWW   W W      W",
"W     W   W   W W WWWW W",
"WWW   W   WWWWW W   WWWW",
"W W      WW            W",
"W W   WWWW   WWW WWW   W",
"W     W    E   W       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

running = True
while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
    
    # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(-2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -2)
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.move(0, 2)
    
    # Just added this to make it slightly fun ;)
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        raise SystemExit
    
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)   
    # Draw the scene
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Потому что вы продолжаете рисовать желтый квадратик pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect) вместо игрока.